# What is this component? TM22

Tags: components

A neighbor has a heated bird bath that ceased working. I've extracted the broken component (a terminal rusted off) which appears to be a thermal switch, but I'm not finding what the specs are to order a new component.

[image: Thermal Switch?]

What I can read on the component:
TM22
125V15A
025A5
2010

I'm assuming that the thermal cutoff should be just above freezing.
Obviously it's 125V 15 Amp, but what do the other pieces mean?

Comment: I did, but my Google foo is failing me. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a snap-action thermostat, of a common general type. There are many variations of this kind of thermostat and many manufacturers producing similar products (eg. KSD301).

The exact specifications are not obvious, at least to me. It could be a 25°C N.C. thermostat with 5°C tolerance. This kind of thermostat may have 15°C or 20°C hysteresis, so if it shuts off at 20-30°C it may not turn on again until 5-10°C.
But that's just a guess. If you look at spec sheets from manufacturers of similar (birdbath) products to the ailing product, they may divulge that information. These parts are also customizable in mechanical and connection details, temperature, hysteresis, special tolerances etc. (within limits, they are crude mechanical snap-disk gadgets, not precision devices) for OEMs who place large orders.

Your best bet may be to approach the manufacturer for a spare part, particularly since this device is most likely switching the mains directly. Substitutions unauthorized by the manufacturer may compromise safety and will likely compromise approvals.